# DataGridView become ReadOnly with Linq using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, linq, datagridview

I am implementing a system using C# ( Windows Forms ) with Entity Frame work and Linq.

The `DataGridView` works well when using normal linq statement, but when I used "Join", the `DataGridView` Become read Only and I cant edit anything.

Example: DataGridView work well with this statement :

```
var query = from d in db.Device select d;
        dgvDevices.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

but it become non-editable with this query :

```
var query = from u in db.Users join d in db.Device on u.id equals d.AssignedTo 
            select new { d.id, d.Name, d.OwnerName,
                         d.OwnerPhoneNumber, d.Details, User = u.Name };
dgvDevices.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Using a `List` as a `DataSource` for a `DataGridView` is not a good idea. You are trying to populate a 2D control (`DataGridView`) with 1D information (`List`). The most logical type is `DataTable`. In any case, this fact does not explain the read-only problem you are complaining about. PS: in the future, please provide an adequate definition of all the variables in the code you are posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of nature of anonymous types that are read only.

> [Anonymous Types (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx)
>
> Anonymous types provide a convenient way to encapsulate a set of
>   read-only properties into a single object without having to explicitly
>   define a type first.

To overcome this limitation you can create your own class and shape the output of query with your own class.