# Editing RadGridView with Anonymous Linq Datasource - C# Telerik WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, radgridview

How to edit Radgridview rows with anonymous linq datasource?

Anonymous linq datasource means getting data with `select new`.

The user can enter edit mode but after changing a text, it will be the same as before. for example if the value of cell is `123` and user changes it to `456` then presses enter, it will become `123` again!!!

I tried managing `CellEndEdit` event but nothing. It seems while using anonymous types as datasource the Radgridview will be read-only. How to solve this problem?

I know the edited values will not submit somewhere, But I need to keep edited values visible on the grid.

Comment: Have you tried using dynamic?

Comment: What is dynamic?

Comment: Refer this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic

I think that you should use dynamic instead of anonymous type

Comment: Possible faster solution is create a class instead of anonymous? Unless you have some reason not to do it

Comment: Yes, using a class is good, but I have so many grid views with so many data types. Creating a class for everyone I think is not a good way.

Comment: [Anonymous types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) provide a convenient way to encapsulate a set of **read-only properties** into a single object without having to explicitly define a type first.

Comment: [DataGridView become ReadOnly with Linq using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32871589/3110834)