# Linq to DataGridView --> How enable edit cell?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a problem with editing a cell in my DataGridView.

When I retrieve data from LINQ I have set to false in ReadOnly.

```csharp
public class Cumst
{
    public string Month { get; set; }
    public double Quantity { get; set; }

}
```

My Linq query:

```csharp
  var juxtaPos = (from test21 in repos.GetTable<Lesson_21>() 
                  where test21.ID == id && test21.Product == "IPHONE" 
                  select (new Cumst 
                  { 
                      Month = test21.Month, 
                      Quantity = Convert.ToDouble(test21.Quantity) 
                  })
                  ).ToList();

  dgvJuxtaposition.DataSource = juxtaPos;
```

When I receive data using SQL String Edit cell is enabled... I do not know why it does not work for Linq

Comment: Hm, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32871589/datagridview-become-readonly-with-linq-using-c-sharp) suggests to use a class but you are doing that already.. The basic idea is probably that you need the ability to write changes back to the datasource. Easy for a DataTable, no sure about a List.

Comment: using this it works just fine: `List<Tuple<string, double>> data = new List<Tuple<string, double>>();
data.Add(new Tuple<string, double>("AA", 123));
data.Add(new Tuple<string, double>("ABA", 10023));
data.Add(new Tuple<string, double>("cAA", 1223));
data.Add(new Tuple<string, double>("ddAA", 1423));
data.Add(new Tuple<string, double>("eeeAA", 3123));
var juxtaPos = data.Select(x => new Cumst() { Month =  x.Item1, Quantity = x.Item2 }).ToList();
`

Answer (score 0):

Use a BindingSource as DataSource and assign a BindingList with the data to the BindingSource

See [Advantages BindingList above List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243950/listt-vs-bindinglistt-advantages-disadvantages)

In the constructor, probably in InitializeComponent:

```
BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
dgv.DataSource = bindingSource;
```

When data arrives:

```
void DisplayCumst(IEnumerable<Cumst> cumst)
{
     BindingList<Cumst> bindingList = new BindingList(cumst.ToList());
     bindingSource.DataSource = bindingList;
}
```